# Drools - Not all actions are executed when rule fires

Tags: java, drools

At the moment, I have a large decision table with a lot of conditions/actions. The decision table has always worked until I have recently added a new action. It does not seem to be executing.

As I'm unable to show the whole file, this is the extract of the most important columns (be aware that there are more conditions):
[image: Partial list of conditions]

Below are the actions that are defined on the "orig" object:
[image]

The following fields are updated through the setter:

- PRM_LIB01
- PRM_LIB09
- PRM_LIB10

However, PRM_LIB18 is not being updated. Even if I switch around the action of PRM_LIB10 and PRM_LIB18, it's only the column of PRM_LIB10 that gets updated.

When I debug through the code, I see that the RuleBuildContext holds all the setters for the first rule:
[image]

So based on this, I would expect it to execute the setPRM_LIB18("GC") as well, which does not happen.

So then I've tried to see the class file Drools actually generates to see whether everything seems fine, but I'm unable to properly view the generated bytecode.

I'm really at a loss why it doesn't work. Does anyone have a clue or how I could debug the actual calling of the actions to maybe see why it's not executed?

Comment: Are you sure none of your other actions is interfering? For example, what is `blankOutPremiumFreeFields(orig)` doing?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite unlikely. How do you ascertain that this action isn't executed? Is there another rule that might also modify PRM_LIB18?

For quick debugging, add another action column containing a printout of the modified object - at least the modified fields.

If you still haven't a clue, try this code and report back with the full/truncated to essentials output.

```
private void testSpreadsheet(){
  File dtf = new File( dtPath );
  InputStream is;
  try {
    is = new FileInputStream( dtf );
    SpreadsheetCompiler ssComp = new SpreadsheetCompiler();
    String s = ssComp.compile( is, InputType.XLS );
    System.out.println( "=== Begin generated DRL ===" );
    System.out.println( s );
    System.out.println( "=== End generated DRL ===" );
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```